# Backbone Marionette redisplaying (showing) a nested layout fails due to 'undefined' region

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have a App with nested layouts. The top level layout being at the App level and the second level at one of its region. When I show the second level layout I trigger an event to show the  regions of the second level layout. This works fine the first time but when I swap the second level layout with some other view or layout and display it again it fails. The problem is recreated at http://jsfiddle.net/mzafer/VLY4t/

In the screen click on "Content1" followed by "Content 2". You'll see the second level layout's region displayed ("This is the actual region1 content" & "This is the actual region2 content"). Now click on "Content1" followed by "Content 2" again.. this time the actual content is not displayed but just the placeholders. During the second time the "thisView.region1" is undefined.

Any idea what is causing the region to get undefined ?

Thanks
Zafer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with the code.

First, you should be using `MyApp.vent.bindTo()` instead of `MyApp.vetn.bind()` to ensure proper management of the event.

Second, you need to unbind from the event when the layout view is closed. What's happening now is that, because you don't unbind, you end up with a closed view (the first instance) still trying to access its region elements, which no longer exist.

In the future, you can detect this by appending `this.cid` to your `console.log` statement. For instance:

```
console.log('Responding to an event.', this.cid);
```

I tweaked your code to make it work, with two changes mentioned above: http://jsfiddle.net/VLY4t/14/

Comment: +1 with 1 minor point: instead of using MyApp.vent.bindTo in your view, you should use `this.bindTo` in the view. That way the cleanup is handled for you when the view is closed: `this.bindTo(MyApp.vent, "some:event", this.whateverCallback, this);`

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I thought that the old view may be lingering out but was not sure to detect it.

Comment: Also Derick, while you are here, can you point me to a resource that explains the use of vent.on vs vent.bind vs vent.bindTo.

Comment: @DerickBailey Aha! I was trying to figure out how to do it so it's automatic, but it wasn't obvious from reading the source and the docs. It would be helpful to add this usecase to `docs/marionette.eventbinder.md` and `docs/marionette.application.md`, which currently uses `bind` in the example.

Comment: this wiki page might help explain things a bit more: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/wiki/When-to-use-the-EventBinder - please let me know if you think it needs more info, or go ahead and update the page yourself. i love seeing community contributions :)

Comment: Notice: `bindTo` has been replaced with `listenTo` (Marionette v1.0.0.0 rc3)